# Ionic --prod build freezes CLI

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to build my Ionic 3 Application via the CLI `ionic cordova build android --prod`.

Previously this command has worked without any issue, now it's freezing on the `webpack` step, right after `copy finished`.

```
# npm run ionic:build --prod

> ionic-app@ ionic:build /Users/personal/Documents/ionic-app
> ionic-app-scripts build

[10:47:11]  ionic-app-scripts 3.1.9
[10:47:11]  build prod started ...
[10:47:11]  clean started ...
[10:47:11]  clean finished in 1 ms
[10:47:11]  copy started ...
[10:47:11]  deeplinks started ...
[10:47:11]  deeplinks finished in 327 ms
[10:47:11]  ngc started ...
[10:47:29]  ngc finished in 17.34 s
[10:47:29]  preprocess started ...
[10:47:29]  preprocess finished in 1 ms
[10:47:29]  webpack started ...
[10:47:29]  copy finished in 18.16 s
```

I've tried to run this multiple times, and left it for over 3 hours to try and have it complete, in the past it's taken 10-15 minutes, but each time it runs, my CLI becomes unresponsive.

Because the CLI is unresponsive I can't `Ctl+C` out of the terminal - I need to close the window and re-open it. As a result no error messages appear in the build process. Even if I run with the `--verbose` flag.

When I run it without the `--prod` flag such as `ionic cordova build android  --aot --minifyjs --minifycss --optmisejs --release`. It executes no problem.

```
# ionic cordova build android  --aot --minifyjs --minifycss --optmisejs
Running app-scripts build: --aot --minifyjs --minifycss --platform android --target cordova
[11:34:28]  build dev started ...
[11:34:28]  clean started ...
[11:34:28]  clean finished in 4 ms
[11:34:28]  copy started ...
[11:34:29]  deeplinks started ...
[11:34:29]  deeplinks finished in 606 ms
[11:34:29]  ngc started ...
[11:34:50]  ngc finished in 21.28 s
[11:34:50]  preprocess started ...
[11:34:50]  preprocess finished in 2 ms
[11:34:50]  webpack started ...
[11:34:51]  copy finished in 22.85 s
[11:35:18]  webpack finished in 27.32 s
[11:35:18]  uglify started ...
[11:35:18]  sass started ...
[11:35:21]  sass finished in 3.06 s
[11:35:21]  cleancss started ...
[11:35:23]  cleancss finished in 2.64 s
[11:36:13]  uglify finished in 55.15 s
[11:36:13]  postprocess started ...
[11:36:13]  postprocess finished in 17 ms
[11:36:13]  lint started ...
[11:36:13]  build dev finished in 104.69 s
> cordova build android --release

BUILD SUCCESSFUL


Total time: 3.548 secs
Built the following apk(s):
        /Users/personal/Documents/ionic-app/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk
```

Attached is my `Ionic Info` in case it helps.

```
cli packages: (/Users/personal/Documents/ionic-app/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    ios-deploy        : 1.9.2
    ios-sim           : 6.1.2
    Node              : v9.11.1
    npm               : 5.6.0
    OS                : macOS High Sierra
    Xcode             : Xcode 9.3 Build version 9E145

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : /Users/personal/Library/Android/sdk

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Comment: I have the same problems, do you have found a solution?

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet, so instead I just run with the individual flags `ionic cordova build android  --aot --minifyjs --minifycss --optmisejs --release`

Comment: Did you try `node --max-old-space-size=4096 ${PATH}/ionic cordova build android --prod`?